# R - Start with initial investment at first row, then multiply by price return if condition is met

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, finance, moving-average

I have a price time series, and I'm trying to create a function that will, in a new given column :

- For the first row (the 1st day of the price time series), have a value of 100 (example of initial investment)
- Then, for subsequent rows, multiply the 100 of inital investment to today's price / yesterday's price, IF a condition is met (here, ma 10 > ma 30).

Here is my code :

```
inv <- function(x){
if(length(x) <2  ){x = 100} 
  else if(data$ma10 > data$ma30 && length(x) > 1){x = shift(x, 1L, type ="lag") * data$price / shift(data$price, 1L, type = "lag")}
  else if(data$ma10 < data$ma30 && length(x) > 1){x = shift(x, 1L, type = "lag")}
 }
data$invest = inv(data$invest)
```

And here is how to reproduce the data :

```
# Random prices 
data = data.table(price = rnorm(1:300, mean = 100))
#Moving average function 
mav <- function(x,n=30) if(length(x) >= n)stats::filter(x,rep(1/n,n), sides=1) else NA_real_ 
data$ma30 = as.numeric(mav(data$price, n = 30))
data$ma10 = as.numeric(mav(data$price, n = 10))
#Remove NAs 
data = subset(data, ma30 != "NA")
```

Unfortunately my function does not work and only yields value around 1 accross all observations.

Any tips :) ?

Comment: For a start, you want `x=100`, not `x==100` - the second is a logical test, so will be TRUE or FALSE but will not change `x`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). But then, how can I change the value of x ? I thought the part between {} would be the result if the IF statement was true. I can for instance add if(....) { x = shift(x, 1L, type = "lag")}. Tried it but does not work

Comment: Your data does not initially have a column called `invest`, but you are calling `inv(data$invest)`, so sending a NULL value to the function, which might be why it comes back with unexpected values.  Perhaps you mean `inv(data$price)`?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :) ! Indeed, I guess the fact that `invest` is not the value to put in the function. But no, it cannot be price because the variable i'm trying to create is new : it has to be 100 in the first observation, and then be multiplied by today's price/yesterday's price if `ma10 > ma30`, or stay the same if otherwise. To sum up, i'm creating a function that creates a new variable based on other variables.

Answer (score 0):

From your `data` as defined, you could just do

```
data$invest = 100 * cumprod(c(1,ifelse(data$ma10 > data$ma30,                             
                    data$price / shift(data$price, 1, type="lag"),
                    1)[-1]))
```

basically this is creating a virtual column of year-by-year increase factors with the `ifelse` statement, removing the first value (`NA` due to the lag) and replacing it with `1`, then taking the cumulative product of these and multiplying by your start value of `100`.

Note that you need `data.table` loaded to use the `shift` function.  Otherwise you could use `lag` to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) ! I see how this formula could work, but for some reason, it only yields "NAs" in the new `invest` column. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Ok just solved the problem. The `shift(price, 1L, type = "lag")`did not work. So I just took the open price from today instead of the close price from yesterday. And it works. Thanks so much for the suggestion, did not know this function

Comment: @JBR Well done - sorry about that - I've updated the answer to replace that first NA in the virtual column with a 1, so it should now work.